# Box2D : Body with no fixtures

Tags: box2d

I would like to use b2Body to integrate effects (explosion, smoke, etc) for simplicity: b2Body provides position. Such a body will contain no fixtures. Only a texture would be rendered.

So I have multiples questions:

- Does a body without fixtures can have a velocity, and/or detect collisions ?
- Does a body with no fixtures consume more CPU ? If so, should I also sleepor disable the body?

Answer (score 0):

A body is a collection of fixtures. So no fixtures means non-existent body.

Does a body without fixtures can have a velocity, and/or detect collisions ?
No. There is nothing to move and nothing to collide.

Does a body with no fixtures consume more CPU ?
No.

If you purely want box2D to keep track of a position maybe consider using a sensor. This is a non-existent box2D object which registers collisions in whatever shape you set up.

https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sensors

Comment: You can call CreateBody(), so you have a body with a position without any fixtures.